# How to make APK standalone from Kivy and python on WINDOWS?

Tags: android, python, linux, windows, kivy

How to make APK file from Kivy and python? I know it's possible to use buildozer and python-for-android, but it's only possible on Linux OS. So, is there anyway to do it on windows?

I use Python 3.4.4 and Kivy 1.9.1

Comment: Just on a VM, I guess

Answer (score 1):

currently no, for now linux is the only option we have

Answer (score 0):

While there's no official option other then using VM, people try to implement it. You may be interested in [this tutorial](https://github.com/el3/kivy/blob/2f6678d449a05491a844cc807838de7a5b6504fa/doc/sources/guide/packaging-android-windows.rst). Note, that it's not part of kivy (yet), but part of [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4763) PR.